# How to solve "Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible" while using Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox, mozilla, geckodriver

I want to use selenium with geckodriver. So I have installed firefox and Geckodriver. But when I just run a simple selenium Application I get a dialoge box with the error.

My Code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/usr/bin/geckodriver");

     WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
     driver2.get("https://google.com");
```

Selenium Log:

> mozrunner::runner INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "--marionette" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofileBF85Lf"
>
> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException:
> Process unexpectedly closed with status 1 Build info: version:
> '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time: '2018-11-06T11:42:16' System
> info: host: 'my-thinkpad', ip: '192.168.100.117', os.name: 'Linux',
> os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.15.0-33-generic', java.version:
> '13.0.2' Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver

But the main Problem I get as dialogbox:

> Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or
> inaccessible.

When I just run the /usr/bin/firefox ... command in terminal without the profile parameter it works. I got the tip from several tutorials to delete the .mozilla directory in my home directory, but there is no .mozilla folder. Im using Kubuntu 22.04. Is there any way to start geckodriver without profile parameter or solve this problem?

Comment: by default Selenium will create a temporary profile for use during the session.  Seems like it's having trouble creating that.  Check permissions maybe? (for driver and browser)  You could also set the driver to use an existing profile.  (but always better to test from clean state...)  If permissions are an issue, you still might have an issue even when using an already existing profile.  The browser will also create a temporary location for cookies and session specific variables methinks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the profile gets stored in the directory where there is no permission to write. So, it would obviously fail.

**Solution:**

1. enter `export TMPDIR=$HOME/Downloads/ geckodriver`

In my case, my geckodriver is in `Downloads` so I exported TMPDIR to the `Downloads`.

**Or try this:**

Just move the geckodriver to any other directory where there is permission to write like `Downloads` or `Documents` and try the above solution.